# Stacked Bar Chart with Line Chart not working in R with plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying top prepare stacked bar chart with line chart and two y axis in R using plotly, but line part is not displaying. Both y axis are fine, stacked bar chart also works. Line chart by itself also works, but not together with stacked bar chart. When I tried it with only one y axis chart had all components, but because of different scale it's not visualizing data well enough. Here is code with sample data:

```
library(plotly)

#data
big <- c(300000,400000,500000,600000,500000,600000)
v1 <- c(3,4,5,5,4,3)
v2 <-c(3,4,5,5,4,3)
Date <- c("Jan 2016","Feb 2016","Mar 2016","Apr 2016","May 2016","June 2016")
df <- data.frame(big, v1, v2, Date)

#plot
p1 <- plot_ly(
   x = df$Date,
   y = df$big,
   type="scatter"
)

p2 <- add_trace(
   p1,
   x = df$Date,
   y = df$v2,
   type = "bar",
   yaxis="y2")

p25 <- add_trace(
   p2,
   x = df$Date,
   y = df$v1,
   type = "bar",
   yaxis="y2"
)

p3 <- layout(p25, 
             xaxis = list(
                title = "Month"
             ),
             yaxis = list(
                title = "big"
             ),
             yaxis2=list(
                title = "little",
                tickfont = list(color = "red"),
                overlying="y",
                side="right"
             ),
             barmode="stack"
)

p3
```

Any idea how to correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
# data
big <- c(300000,400000,500000,600000,500000,600000)
v1 <- c(3,4,5,5,4,3)
v2 <-c(3,4,5,5,4,3)
Date <- c("Jan 2016","Feb 2016","Mar 2016","Apr 2016","May 2016","June 2016")
df <- data.frame(big, v1, v2, Date)

library(plotly)

df %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~Date) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~v1,
           name = "bar1") %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~v2,
           name = "bar2") %>%
  add_lines(y = ~big,
            name = "line",
            yaxis = "y2") %>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack",
         yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y",
                       side = "right"),
         barmode = "stack")
```

[image]