# Create secondary axis for stacked barplot with line trace in R plotly

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, r-plotly

I am implementing a function which builds a stacked % barplot with an additional line trace.  I can create the stacked bar plot using either a wide-form or a long-form dataframe.  The two code sections below produce plots that look essentially the same:

Using a wide-form dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)  # install.packages("plotly")

# simple example data for SO post
some_dates = c(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-02-01'),
               as.Date('2021-03-01'), as.Date('2021-04-01'))

bar1 = c(0.25,0.45,0.65,0.75)
bar2 = c(0.60,0.40,0.20,0.10)
bar3 = c(0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15)

line_data = c(0,1,2,3)

# wide form dataframe
df_bars = data.frame("db" = some_dates, "b1" = bar1,
                     "b2" = bar2, "b3" = bar3)

df_line = data.frame("line_dates" = some_dates, "line" = line_data)

plot_so1 = plot_ly(x = df_bars$db,
                   y = df_bars[[colnames(df_bars)[2]]],
                   type = 'bar',
                   name = colnames(df_bars)[2]) %>% 
  layout(title = 'My plot title',
         xaxis = list(title = 'db'),
         yaxis = list(title = 'CatProportions'),
         barmode = 'stack',
         showlegend = TRUE)

# Now loop through the rest of the columns except for the ones already used.
# This is done because "in the wild", the plot is being built in a function
# that has data which is passed to it so the number and names of the columns
# that are used to build the plot are not know in advance.
for (col_index in 3:length(some_dates)) {
  plot_so1 =
    add_trace(plot_so1,
              x = df_bars$db,
              y = df_bars[[colnames(df_bars)[col_index]]],
              name = colnames(df_bars)[col_index])
}
```

Using a long-form dataframe:

```
## long form of dataframe #########################
df_bars_long = df_bars %>%
  pivot_longer(!db, names_to = "Categories", values_to = "CatProportions")
# build same plot from long form dataframe
plot_so2 = plot_ly(data = df_bars_long,
                   x = ~db, y = ~CatProportions,
                   color = ~Categories,
                   type = "bar") %>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack")

## above works, now try to add the line trace #####
plot_so2 = plot_ly(data = df_bars_long,
                   x = ~db, y = ~CatProportions,
                   color = ~Categories,
                   type = "bar") %>% 
  # add_trace(x = df_line$line_dates,
  #           y = df_line$line,
  #           type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = 'my line',
  #           line = list(color = '#000000')) %>% 
  layout(title = 'My plot title',
         xaxis = list(title = 'db'),
         yaxis = list(title = 'CatProportions'),
         barmode = 'stack',
         showlegend = TRUE)
```

[image]

I understand that using the long form to create plots like this is best practice, but I show both methods above because I want to add a line trace using data from another dataframe which has one column for the x values and one column for the y values and have only been able to add this trace using the wide-form which I can do by adding the following code segment to the wide-form code:

```
plot_so1 = add_trace(plot_so1,
                     x = df_line$line_dates,
                     y = df_line$line,
                     type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = 'my line',
                     line = list(color = '#000000'))
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

My primary question is, how do I create a secondary y-axis for the line trace from the wide from dataframe code?  My secondary question is: can the final plot I'm looking for be done with the long form dataframe and if so, how?

This post got me started on this problem:

[Stacked Bar Chart with Line Chart not working in R with plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371261/stacked-bar-chart-with-line-chart-not-working-in-r-with-plotly)

but it didn't involve a stacked barplot which seems to make life more interesting.

Comment: At the moment the line and the bar charts are plotted on the same scale (i.e. [0,3]). What would you like the secondary y-axis for? Do you mean that you would like the left y-axis to be [0,1] and the right [0,3]?

Comment: @VitaminB16 Yes, exactly. Want line axis on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is unchanged:

```
some_dates = c(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-02-01'),
               as.Date('2021-03-01'), as.Date('2021-04-01'))
line_data = c(0,1,2,3)

# wide form dataframe
df_bars = data.frame("db" = some_dates, "b1" = bar1,
                     "b2" = bar2, "b3" = bar3)

df_line = data.frame("line_dates" = some_dates, "line" = line_data)
```

If we want to include a line into the plot, we need to know the y values of the line at each date, so we merge `df_line` with `df_bars_long` using `merge()`:

```
df_bars_long = df_bars %>%
  pivot_longer(!db, names_to = "Categories", values_to = "CatProportions") %>%
  merge(df_line, by.y = "line_dates", by.x = "db") %>%
  group_by(db) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(line = ifelse(duplicated(line), NA, line))

> df_bars_long
           db Categories CatProportions line
1  2021-01-01         b1           0.25    0
2  2021-01-01         b2           0.60   NA
3  2021-01-01         b3           0.15   NA
4  2021-02-01         b1           0.45    1
..         ..         ..             ..   ..
```

Then, the plot:

```
plot_so2 <- plot_ly(data = df_bars_long,
                    x = ~db, y = ~CatProportions,
                    color = ~Categories,
                    type = "bar") %>%
  add_lines(y = ~line,
            name = "my line",
            line = list(color = '#000000'),
            showlegend = TRUE,
            yaxis = "y2") %>%
  layout(title = 'My plot title',
         xaxis = list(title = 'db'),
         yaxis = list(title = 'CatProportions'),
         barmode = 'stack',
         yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y",
                       side = "right", range = range(na.omit(df_bars_long$line))))
> plot_so2
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have 3 lines on top of each other in the way you put together the dataframe, but this looks fixable. This gets most of way, so am going to accept this as the solution.

Comment: I have fixed the problem. We can set the duplicated `line` values to `NA`. I've updated the solution code.